# Allowing Only One Entry Per IP using PHP

Tags: php, redirect, ip, limit

For each entry on the site i want ip's to be logged on a txt file as a list, and at the same time check if they visited the site earlier, if yes to be redirected somewhere else.
So i want to allow only one entry per IP using PHP, by checking that list.

```
<?php
$fname = "ips.txt";
$file=fopen($fname,'a+');
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
fwrite($file,"
".$ip." ");
fclose($file);
?>
```

This logs perfectly every ip that entered the site, now i need an edit from this:

```
<?php $blacklist = array("123.456.789", "456.789.123", "789.123.456");
if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $blacklist)) {
    header("Location: http://google.com");
    exit();
} ?>
```

to read the ips.txt file and redirect them.

Beginner at PHP here.

Comment: sooooo.. *what have you tried so far*? plus: you should probably use a database instead.

Comment: I added a few details, check the edit please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to capture a user's ip.

I would suggest using an SQL database rather than a file for checking though.

Comment: As i said i am allowed to use PHP in this case only.

Comment: Do some research into storing data in json format in files then

Comment: Okay thank you, im very new at this thanks for the reply/and time.